# js ( jquery ) passing variable names in string to 2nd function before the 2nd function is initialised

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two scripts + two json.

script one.html

```
 var myArr = [];
    myArr .push (
            {myOptStr:'<option value="'+myAjaxVar.valOne+'">'+myAjaxVar.valtwo+'</option>'},  
            {myOptStr:'<option value="'+myAjaxVar.valthree+'">'+myAjaxVar.valfour+'</option>'}, 
    )
 ...
 //load two.js via ajax as dataType: "script",
 ...

 // Call one
 myFun(myArr[0].myOptStr, "myJsonZero");
// Call two
 myFun(myArr[1].myOptStr, "myJsonOne");
```

script two.js

```
function myFun(myOpts, myJson) {
   $.ajax({
     url: myJson
     ...
    success: function (data) {
       ...
       $.each(data, function (abc, myAjaxVar) {
          myOptrows += myOpts;
       ...
```

this generates an error on one.html as `myAjaxVar` does not yet exist.

Is it possible to pass `myOptStr` as a string so it can be interpreted as a string+var in the loaded two.js?

ie in two.js, the `myOpts` is interpreted as

```
myOptrows += '<option value="'+myAjaxVar.valOne+'">'+myAjaxVar.valtwo+'</option>'
```

Comment: *"interpreted as a string+var"*: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: You can set `myOptStr` to a function and pass a function as the first parameter to `myFun` instead of a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `myOptStr` properties to functions and pass a function as the first parameter to `myFun` instead of a string.

Here is an example

```
var myArr = [];
myArr .push (
        {
          myOptStr : function(myAjaxVar){
                         return '<option value="'+myAjaxVar.valOne+'">'+myAjaxVar.valtwo+'</option>';
                     }
        }
)
...
myFun(myArr[0].myOptStr, "myJsonZero");
...
function myFun(myOpts, myJson) {
    ...
    $.each(data, function (abc, myAjaxVar) {
          myOptrows += myOpts(myAjaxVar);
          ...
    }
}
```

Comment: outstanding! I would not have thought of that approach as possible. Thanks for the very fast answer that was clear.

Comment: @artvanderlay I'm glad I could help. Good luck.